# How use a loop within a loop to display all results for a certain field?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `MySQL/PHP` and have a search results page that pulls in data from several tables using 2 joins. I get all the data just fine. For example, there are 3 currencies for a particular record (Store), and I am pulling them from my currencies table.
However, I can only display the first currency in my results (Euro). I want the results field for currency to display all currencies from the currencies table for the selected Store and echo like `(Euro, Dollars, Yen)`

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM store 
 //joins part of query
 where store.id=1
 GROUP BY store.name
 ";

 $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


 Name: <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
 Banking Currency Options:</b> <?php echo $row['currency']; ?>  
   //only displays first currency of the three records in the currency table. 
   //How do I return all 3 results/currencies here, separated by a comma?  
   //Like "Euro, Dollars, Yen"
   //I need some sort of the second loop for currency

 Languages:</b> <?php echo $row['language']; ?>
```

Comment: @Strawberry I DON'T...each  value is stored as a record in a seperate table (currency). But when I display the results I want to display them like "Euro, Dollars, Yen" Currently I only get "Euro" (first result)

Comment: Get rid of the GROUP BY clause, and instead just implode the array.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

Dataset

```
SELECT colors, products FROM my_table ORDER BY colors,products;
+--------+----------+
| colors | products |
+--------+----------+
| Blue   | Bag      |
| Blue   | Belt     |
| Blue   | Biro     |
| Blue   | Bucket   |
| Blue   | Cotton   |
| Blue   | Pants    |
| Blue   | Paper    |
| Blue   | Shoes    |
| Yellow | Cap      |
| Yellow | Car      |
| Yellow | Hat      |
| Yellow | Phone    |
| Yellow | Pouch    |
| Yellow | Sandal   |
| Yellow | Shirt    |
| Yellow | Socks    |
| Yellow | Track    |
+--------+----------+
```

Code

```
<?php

include('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "SELECT colors, products FROM my_table ORDER BY colors,products;";


$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$array[] = $row;
}

foreach($array as $v){
$new_array[$v['colors']][] = $v['products'];
}

print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
    Array
    (
        [Blue] => Array
            (
                [0] => Bag
                [1] => Belt
                [2] => Biro
                [3] => Bucket
                [4] => Cotton
                [5] => Pants
                [6] => Paper
                [7] => Shoes
            )

        [Yellow] => Array
            (
                [0] => Cap
                [1] => Car
                [2] => Hat
                [3] => Phone
                [4] => Pouch
                [5] => Sandal
                [6] => Shirt
                [7] => Socks
                [8] => Track
            )

    )
```

Hopefully, it shouldn't be too much of a stretch for you to spit this out as comma delimited string, or a bit of JSON, or whatever.

Comment: This might be a good approach but I am also returning about 10 other variables for the store such as name, address, country, etc, so I don't think I can use DISTINCT colors because then I do not get all the other results...

Comment: This approach is still fine. The statements that parse the 1-D array just become a little more complex.